# How to add indentation at the start of new paragraph?

Tags: indentation, paragraphs

I am a wirting thesis, and I have to add indentation at the start of each new paragraph? my code for paragraph:

```
       \renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5} % set linespacing = 1.5; equivalent to word file = 1.5
\usepackage{indentfirst} % indent first paragraph after each chapter/section
        \edef\restoreparindent{\parindent=\the\parindent\relax} % define new function to save indentation
\usepackage{enumitem} % itemize spacing control

        \setlist{itemsep = 0pt, parsep = 0pt}
\usepackage[nodayofweek]{datetime} % live date display
\usepackage{parskip} % paragraph spacing in the main body only
        \restoreparindent % restore the previous indentation
        \setlength{\parskip}{5pt} % paragraph spacing in the body
```

Comment: `\setlength{\parindent}{1em} % indentation of 1em` (and remove all the commands playing with `\parindent`)

Comment: @Fran its not  working

Comment: Then you have something changing `\parindent` again. If you are unable to clean that code, post a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Please, **minimal**, but still **compilable**, and of course, still showing your problem.

Comment: Don't load `\usepackage{parskip}`, whose main aim is to remove the indentation.

Comment: indentation is the default behaviour. the only purpose of the parskip package is to remove indentation and use vertical space instead.